VS always decompiles Interfaces and Enums instead of showing the code via sourcelink
I referenced my nuget package supporting sourcelink and tried to open the sourcecode for those interfaces/enums by pressing F12 on a type in Visual Studio:
While a class from this package can be opened in sourcelink, Interfaces and Enums always get decompiled instead of using sourcelink. I can't see any comment, etc. from the sourcecode.
I already checked the package: The package gets shown with "valid sourcelink" entry in the NuGet Package Explorer.
I opened the DLLs properties using right mouse click and checked the tab "PDB sources": I see links for each class, whether it contains interfaces, enums or classes and I am even able to see the sourcecode for every file and view the sourcecode in my browser.
What can I do, to view the source code of interfaces and enums as well as for classes in Visual Studio?

Can you share the un-produtive code? I am unable to reproduce the same situation, I am using newtonsoft json package.
